# Is it possible to have multiple nitrogen atoms bonded to one carbon atom?

Tags: stability, amines

So I was wondering, if we replaced two of the hydrogens in methane with amine groups, would it be a stable compound? What about for R groups of varying size?

Similarly, if I tried to make a compound with a terminal acetal except I now replace the hydrogen at the terminal carbon with another -OR group, would that be stable? Or is it too much steric hindrance?

Comment: Addressing the title: guanidine NH=C(NH2)2 and urea CO(NH2)2

Comment: Uhh, tetranitromethane?

Comment: also amidines are a thing

Comment: also ortho-esters are a thing too, I think that answers your question about a carbon bonded to three oxygens.  also maybe carbonate esters.

Comment: Title should be rather something like "Stability of aminals"...

Answer (score 6):

A carbon atom can be bonded to as many as four nitrogen atoms, with those nitrogen atoms bonded to additional alkyl groups. Tetrakis(dimethylamino)methane, $\ce{C(N(CH3)2)4}$, has been known since 1966 [[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00964a071). The compound is stable enough to allow finding a reported melting point of 122.5-124.5°C.

Alkylating the nitrogen atoms, at least with methyl groups as above, actually gives a more stable compound than would be obtained with $\ce{N–H}$ bonds despite the steric appearances. With the alkylation, possible decomposition by labile exchange of protons (liberating ammonia) would be excluded.

**Reference**

Harold Weingarten and William A. White (1966). "Preparation of Tetrakis(dimethylamino)methane". *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **88**, 12, 2885.
https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00964a071